# Parallelization and resource allocation with SLURM bash script

Tags: r, parallel-processing, slurm

I have a possibility to do processing on a HPC environment, where task managing and resource allocation are controlled by SLURM batch job system. However, I have not found the right configurations how to utilize the allocated resources within R efficiently. I have tried to allocate 20 CPU's to one task in SLURM, using plan(multicore) -function of future package in R. After running test runs with different count of CPUs allocated, efficiency statistics suggested that with these settings only one of the CPU's allocated was used during the test runs.

Slurm bash script presented below

```
#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH --job-name=pointsToRaster
#SBATCH --account=project_num
#SBATCH --time=00:10:00
#SBATCH --output=output_%j.txt
#SBATCH --error=error_%j.txt
#SBATCH --nodes=1
#SBATCH --ntasks-per-node=1
#SBATCH --cpus-per-task=20
#SBATCH --mem-per-cpu=15G
#SBATCH --partition=small

#A 10 MINUTE LONG TEST RUN

#load module
module load r-env-singularity

# Bind threads to individual cores
export OMP_PROC_BIND=true

#Run script
srun singularity_wrapper exec Rscript --no-save pointClouds.R
```

This bash script allocates resources and executes script pointClouds.R. In the R script availableCores() ensures that reserved CPU's are found, and supportsMulticore() ensures that environment and settings support multicore processing. Script content presented below.

```
#set working directory
setwd(dir = "/scratch/project_2001456/lasFiles")

#load packages
library(sf)
library(sp)
library(raster)
library(rgdal)
library(lidR)
library(future)

####### SET COMPUTATIONAL CONFIGURATIONS ##########

# Parallelization settings:
print(availableCores()) #ensure that reserved CPU's are found
print(supportsMulticore())#ensure that environment and settings support multicore-processing
plan(multicore) #strategy to for resolving a future.

#From here on out, I have split one .las file to multiple chunks by their spatial extent. Aim to process all the chunks utilizing parallel processing, but process seems to utilize only one of the allocated CPUs.
```

Any help on how to correctly allocate resources with a SLURM bash script, and efficiently utilize them in parallel processing within R?

Comment: Parts of the question regarding data analysis with lidR are now removed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was found by HPC service provider. For unknown reason `OMP_PLACES=cores` variable which should tie threads/processes to specific cores, appeared to bind all processes to a single core only when running multi-core R jobs. Issue has been solved by rebuilding r-environment singularity-container.